# Elastic Luence query for average result

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am new to Elastic Search and Lucene Syntax.

What I want to know is there anyway to get the average for a specific time period.

For example, I have the following info stored in my index.

```
Index Name Result TimeStamp
a-3    A    7     March 7th 2018, 16:17:35.000
a-3    A    13    March 7th 2018, 16:17:36.000
a-3    B    5     March 7th 2018, 16:17:37.000
```

I would like to write a query to return me that between 16:17:35 and 16:17:38 the average result for A = 10 and B = 5.

Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) and use nested aggregations ([term aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [avg aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-avg-bucket-aggregation.html))

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "TimeStamp": {
        "gte": "2018-03-07 16:17:35",
        "lte": "2018-03-07 16:17:38" 
      }
    }
  }, 

  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Name",
        "size": 10
      }
      , "aggs": {
        "stats": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "Result"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result will look like this

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "name": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "A",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "stats": {
            "value": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "B",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "stats": {
            "value": 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Is there anyway I can convert to this lucene query syntax so I can use it in kibana search bar or grafana ?